# Git master missing

Tags: git

Uh, I created a new repo in git in a a folder with a bunch of prewritten source, but now when I try to push it there is no 'master'. help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to commit the contents of the directory to create an initial commit:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit.'
```

Otherwise there's nothing for Git to push.

Answer (score 1):

Have you done your initial commit?

```
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```